# Rails Engines and jbuilder view tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am building a rails engine that handles a search functionality in my app.

Originally, it was built as a controller concern in an existing app with an associated [routing concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Concerns.html) and json views. This has now been extracted into an engine without ActiveRecord which I hope to able to mount on other apps.

Whether the above is any use to the question I am not sure.

I would like to test my json files (constructed via jbuilder) but am having trouble marrying the specs with the app.

I can't seem to get past this error

```
  1) views/api/search/feed.json should render without error
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template views/api/search/feed with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>["json"]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/***/projects/morse_searchable/spec/dummy/app/views"
         * "/Users/***/projects/morse_searchable/app/views"
```

I feel it could be a number of issues, which one I am not sure.

- Am I testing the engine in the right place?
- In the process of removing Active Record have I messed something up?
- Is this how we normally test json files, let alone json files in engines?

For extra info I've added a [pastebin link to the current folder structure](http://pastebin.com/tky7hLQt) should that shed any light on the issue.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

(using rails 4 and rspec)

Comment: Hello rico_mac - You mention that you are using jbuilder for your json views. It looks like you have `:json` in your formats, but you don't have `:jbuilder` in your handlers. Have you ensured that your engine has jbuilder as a dependency and that it is being required properly?

Answer (score 2):

Any gem you add as a dependency for your rails engine, You need to require the gem in your gem module declaration.

Example:

Location : `engine_root/lib/module_name.rb`

```
require "module_name/engine"
require 'mongoid'
require 'jbuilder'
module module_name
  # Your code goes here...
end
```